# Searching with ThinkingSphinx in a Cucumber feature returns no results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, thinking-sphinx

I am trying to run a feature where a search occurs.  I added the necessary lines that the ThinkingSphinx documentation recommends

```
require 'cucumber/thinking_sphinx/external_world'
Cucumber::ThinkingSphinx::ExternalWorld.new
```

And also disabled using transactions and use DatabaseCleaners truncation instead.  I have my feature setup so after I add a user, I update the index for Sphinx, and then I do a search.

```
Scenario: Add a client to a project
    Given I have a project named "ProjectXYZ"
    And I have a client named "Tom Client" with an email address "tom@email.com"
    And the Sphinx indexes are updated
    And if I search for "Tom" which is a "Client", I have 1 result
```

The search always returns 0 results, even though the user is there.  If I check the count for User.find_by_first_name("Tom").count.should eq(1) it succeeds.

Here are my steps:

**Updating Index**

```
Given 'the Sphinx indexes are updated' do
    # Update all indexes
    ThinkingSphinx::Test.index
    sleep(1.0) # Wait for Sphinx to catch up
end
```

**Searching and checking results**

```
Given /^if I search for "([^"]*)" which is a "([^"]*)", I have (\d+) results?$/ do |query,model,count|
    Rails.const_get(model).search_count(query).should == count.to_i
end
```

I am using Rails 3.0.3, Cucumber 0.9.4, and Cucumber-Rails 0.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing seems out of place thus far... in case you're not already, I would recommend using [my blog post](http://freelancing-gods.com/posts/using_thinking_sphinx_with_cucumber) instead of the official docs as a reference (the latter need updating).

Also: do you have the test/cucumber environment using [a different port](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html) for Sphinx to your development setup? Although if Sphinx isn't running in dev, then that shouldn't get in the way.

Comment: Turns out that Sphinx was searching the development database and not the test database.  Thanks for the help, this was driving me crazy.

Comment: Thanks pat for this answer. Maybe this should be better documented because it seems like a normal problem to have :)

Comment: Can you share how you fixed it?